# Private IP Solution for facebook Real-Time API

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I wrote a app(by C#) that will continuously monitor(polling) my facebook-page mailbox, but I found that there is a Real-Time API for facebook-page, when I send a message to my facebook-page mailbox, facebook will  notice the app that there is a new message. However, It seems that if I want to use the Real-Time API, I need a public IP. When a change occurs, the API sends an http-post request to this public-ip url, but I just have private IP(in some situations and environments). If there are any solutions to makes it works in private-up environment?

Comment: nothing you could do on your devel machine. this would require another machine with a public IP to proxy/forward the request back to your machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution that will let Facebook's servers reach your code with webhooks notifications without your code being reachable at a public IP address available which is listening for Facebook's notificaions

If the machine the code is hosted on has only a private IP, you'll need some sort of proxy with a public IP to forward the relevant requests to that machine